# OpenShift with central Atlassian Stash Git repo management server

Tags: git, openshift, bitbucket-server

I am new to OpenShift PaaS but understand each application has it's own local Git repository.

As far as I can find, the documentation doesn't discuss how to use OpenShift alongside a centralised Git repo management server - Atlassian Stash in our case.

Is this pattern recognised / possible at all?

In our case there are benefits to having a centralised Git repo management server such as a repository browser and README's and the many different plug-ins available, over and above a standalone Git repository.

Many thanks for any pointers, Andrew

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like Jenkins or Travis-ci to manage your application lifecycle, and use webhooks so that when you commit your changes do your central git repo, your continuous integration server will pick up the changes, build your project, and deploy it to openshift.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that thanks @corey112358, but not really what I'm looking for.

We use Jenkins already for CI, but I'm looking for integration with source control management (in particular Atlassian Stash) and all that provides - code review, pull requests, administration, issue tracking integration etc. etc.